# How do I uninstall dj-stripe from my project?

Tags: django, uninstallation

I ran pip uninstall dj-stripe and removed it from INSTALLED_APPS and removed the other settings.py entries. Everything is working, but the DB still has a lot of dj-stripe tables. Is there a quick way to remove these? I ran migrate to create them, but they are not in my models.py file. They were made with something from the dj-stripe installation. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, reinstall dj-stripe into your environment, and add it back to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

A nifty feature of migrations is you can specify which migrations to run, including rollbacks. For example, if you have an app named `polls`, you can roll either forward or backward to your third migration by running

```sh
python manage.py migrate polls 003
```

You can also completely rollback models for an app. For `dj-stripe`

```sh
python manage.py migrate djstripe zero
```

And that's it! Then you can remove it from your environment again.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something pretty simple. Still learning and first time I had to do this.